# How to use form authentication in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I have one application with Form Authentication.I have different levels of users.

When logged as Admin It has to show all the screens and when logged as Client   the data need to restricted.
I have logged as Client in Internet Explorer.After time out Its showing Admin's data  .please tell me the way to get log in page after Timeout.

My Config File sttings are :
`protection="All" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" slidingExpiration="true"`

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: Use different credentials for admin and client.

Comment: I am using different credentials ..But after 30 min ,if the page is reloaded its showing Admin Data automatically.How to avoid this.?

Comment: Create the cookies and see what happen. To logout use LoginStatus control or SingOut method of FormAuthentication class.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all admin accessible pages in one folder and give folder level security to allow only user's in admin role to brose through the pages. And put all the pages to be accessible by users in client role in another folder, with accessible role to be client as well as admin.

Comment: Client and Admin can access all the pages ...But the data should be different in my application...Client should not be able to access all the data....but after 30 min in Client screen all the Admin data is showing..please tell me the way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement role based authorization as per below

```
<location path=”Admin”>
                <authorization>
                 <allow roles=”Admin” />       
                 <deny users=”*” />
                 <deny roles=”*” /> 
                </authorization>
</location> 

<location path=”Members”>
                    <authorization>
                     <allow roles=”Members” />       
                     <deny users=”*” />
                     <deny roles=”*” /> 
                    </authorization>
    </location>
```

Please refer [this nice article](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article979-aspnet-authentication-and-authorization.aspx#Forms%20Authentication) for more details